# Android: Drawable brighter than in Photoshop

Tags: android, android-layout, png, drawable, photoshop

I have to build a Layout for an Android app - based on a photoshop project. I exported the required layers/gfx into png files to use them in my layout.

One png is used as a background of a list item. But it shows up much more brighter than expected. The original png is not that bright.

Why is that? Is that because of the size of the image - because it maybe gets stretched in a way to fill the background of the list item?

Answer (score 0):

Did you saved your png with RGB color method?
Sometimes happens that you save png with CMYK color method, which is better in print world, and in this case your colors will never be the same you see on photoshop.

Comment: in the "save as" dialog i choose "save a copy" what ever that means. CMYK is not checked. The png itself has RGB/8 profile. So i suppose the png is saved with RGB method.

Comment: To check if you're working on correct color method you have to go on menu item "Image" and submenu Mode. The right choice is RGB Color.